# Javascript .pac file

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get a browser to read a .pac file without having the user manually point the browser's automatic config file at the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about Proxy Autoconfiguration?

Basically you have to configure a host name such as wpad.example.com and put the file there named as wpad.dat

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome then you can use the chrome switch `--proxy-pac-url`

For example:

Open cmd.exe as admin

[image]

Make sure to first navigate to the path of Chrome (1st line) in cmd

Notice also that I used another chrome switch which is `unsafe-pac-url` this will allow your pac file to work for HTTPS requests, because otherwise chrome will only apply our PAC file to HTTP requests only.